# Sent Ethereum from Coinbase to Ledger Nano S ETC address by accident

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, coinbase, ledger-nano-s

Date- 20170420

Accidently sent about 46 ETH from Coinbase to Ledger Nano S Address.

The transactions shown below looks like a good transaction but not showing up on either ETH or ETC wallet on ledger nano s. Since i have the keys to the nano s address, shouldn't i be able to send them back to coinbase?

I contacted both ledger and coinbase support but both replies said they will get back to me but it could take a while.

Please tell me im not the only one whose done this! What are we supposed to do? My gut says to wait it out and it will time out by itself because it was sent from one chain to the other... but im not sure. Shouldn't the address exist on both chains?

Details are below. Thank you in advance for you time on this. Cheers.

−$2,300.22 USD TO Ethereum address
0x7D6f82315659316518de07084519C207D9e80dAc

STATUS Transaction confirmed
131 confirmations
6:32PM — April 20, 2017
COMPLETE

Transaction ID on etherscan - 0x65491f150ce5a4fa2fce0f2c3eb3c15911245105136ac30267ea2dd11f4ff116

Answer (score 1):

I made the same mistake and was able to solve it by following the steps explained on one of the support pages on ledgerwallet.com, link [here](http://support.ledgerwallet.com/knowledge_base/topics/i-sent-eth-on-an-etc-address-how-can-i-recover-them?from_search=true).